# How to install same app more than once on same device

Tags: applications, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same app (logged in to different accounts)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-logged-in-to-differen)

I want to install same app more than once on same device. For example: I want to install facebook application 5 times with different accounts.

Is it possible or not?