# Is it possible to install two instances of a same app?

Tags: applications, installation, dual-sim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same app (logged in to different accounts)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-logged-in-to-differen)

I have a dual-sim Android device, an Alcatel Onetouch.

As it has two SIM cards, I'm just wondering if there is any chance of installing two instances of applications such as Whatsapp in order to have it working for both phone numbers.

I have been searching on several forums without finding any valid answer to my question, answers use to be ambiguous.

I would like to clarify this matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Every application in a device has a unique identifier named as application package. You cannot have two applications with the same package name installed in a device. Even if you try to install, it will replace the first one.