# Switch between accounts in Android 4.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-account, multi-user

I would like to know if it's possible to easily switch between two Google accounts in Nexus 4 running Android 4.2 JellyBean.

For example, I have at the moment two Google accounts set up in the device: my personal account and my work account. But if I access Google Analytics, I can only access using my personal account (the first one that was set up).

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you accessing analytics? Through Chrome?

Comment: I access using the Google Analytics app available at Google Play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-logged-in-to-differen).

As a workaround, you can use the data profile feature of [Titanium Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro) with the analytics app.