# How can I run multiple copies of the same app?

Tags: applications

On iPhone it's very easy to clone an app (running multiple copies of the app on the same device); e.g.:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4f_aLSRnQ8

Is it possible to do this on Android?

Comment: If you're using a tablet, you could use two users and add the same account to each and switch between them.

Comment: Also see: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-logged-in-to-differen

Comment: i think it is similar to multiple account app for android, whereas user wants to login 2 whatsapp accounts within single handphone.... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android, the *package name* of the app is what identifies it on the phone: that's what gives it its own space to run in, and it has to be unique in running apps. There are two options to get one app running two instances:

1. If you're on a Jelly Bean tablet, you can do this with multi-user support. Create two user profiles on the tablet, and you can run the app once in each profile. Each user's instance of the app gets its own storage.
2. If you have access to the source code of the app, you can create a new app by changing its package name. Then install the new app. What you end up with is actually two apps, each with one instance, but since they both have the same code and resources, it has the effect you're looking for.

These are the only two ways. If your device doesn't have multi-user support, and you don't have access to the app's source code (i.e. you're not the app's developer), then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an app called parallel space. Not only does it allow you to run multiple instances of the same app, it even allows you to hide installations within the parallel space app itself, set different color schemes and whatnot.

I came across it today in my quest for the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can login with another user, by adding multiple user in your Android device. We can Enable Multiple User Accounts on Android 4.2 and Above.

1. Create another User Account by opening the notification by `double pulldown notification` to get the `other quick settings`.
2. In that other quick settings, on top-right corner you'll find a round icon. That is Admin user icon(if you're using it for first time).
3. Click on it and create a `new user`(it'll remain until you delete it) or use a `guest user`(it'll be deleted after using it, but you can also keep it).
4. After creating `new/guest user`. Just go to `Google Play Store`, install whatever app you want. Don't worry it'll use your existing same app files but not users data, so it won't download a new one.
5. You can login those apps with another id. Like this you can use Whatsapp, hike, facebook, twitter, paytm and more...
6. Before that, go to `more settings` Click and open that created new/guest user's settings and enable `Allow phone calls and SMS`. So that you'll get verification SMS or call.

If any help you can comment it, i'll keep on updating it if any change or improvement.

Answer (score 0):

> If your device doesn't have multi-user support, and you don't have access to the app's source code (i.e. you're not the app's developer), then you're out of luck.

cant we reverse engineer .. like most apps?
open the package in editor
and make changes?

ohhh here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=21819887&postcount=5

> It would be possible if you were to decompile the .apk , edit the manifest file to rename the app to something else so the system thinks its a different apk, then compile, sign it, and install to phone, hassle free. Not too hard