# How to use two whatsapp accounts on one phone

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, accounts, dual-sim

I have a Samsung galaxy Duos and want to use my two whatsapp accounts at the same device. Is it for example possible to run dual two whatsapp client apps on one phone?

Comment: Well, I don't think that would be possible at all but anyway I would rather say over here nothing is impossible for developers at all ! I think I want to know about it too ! So, +1 from my side !

Comment: Yeah, searching on Google did return some results. Probably I'll write the answer if I have some time after understanding the procedure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run multiple copies of the same app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54108/how-can-i-run-multiple-copies-of-the-same-app)

Comment: @RahulParashar I don't think this is quite a duplicate, because if there's a trick that's specific to WhatsApp, that couldn't be posted on the linked question.

Comment: @DanHulme I want to point out,  all in all, whatsapp is an android app. If there is a technique then it can be applied to the all the android app. This is because of how the system (Operating system) is designed.

Comment: @RahulParashar There are already two answers on this question which recommend an alternative WhatsApp app. Obviously that's a solution that doesn't generalise to other apps.

Comment: But, the truth still holds that android app cannot have two instances. These are just workarounds which possibly/tweak-ably work for other apps also.

Answer (score 3):

You can't install an app twice unless you go deep down hacking.

I don't know how WhatsApp works but you may just be able to put multiple accounts to one device. These accounts then may be handled separately by a single app. You can also try to look for alternatives if WhatsApp doesn't support multiple accounts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use two WhatsApp account in a single phone,and here is an alternate method. There are so many application using them you can use dual WhatsApp,
and [Parallel Space](http://parallel-app.com/),
simply install application Parallel Space from Google Play.
After installing, there you will see an option for WhatsApp, using that you can use another WhatsApp account.
Using *Parallel Space* you will use multiple WhatsApp,Hike,Messenger account with a single Application.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to use two account by using two whatsapp(first offical whatsapp,second OGWhatsapp)  [OGWhatsapp](http://ogwhatsapp.en.uptodown.com/android)

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. Thank you for your contribution. This is a good starting for an answer, but could you also mention (or quote) the steps to install it?

Comment: @AndrewT. Its simple download OGwhatsapp the link i provided above and install provide your 1st number. After that you can install offical whatsapp install provide 2nd number. So by this way 2 numbers will be working in a single mobile parallel way. 

Comment: Security and privacy concerns of using a non official "whastapp"? Don't recommend that kind of thing...

Answer (score 0):

A more recent workaround involves using [Disa (Unified Messenger Hub)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disa&hl=en) (available on playstore).

It uses plugin to access services like **WhatsApp**, Telegram etc.

Despite the fact that it is still in beta versions, AFAICT, it has stable release of its plugins and can be a good way to use multiple WhatsApp instances on one device.

The plugins are still bring fine-tuned as currently sone features are still lacking (e.g WhatsApp web, WhatsApp statuses), but the developers promised to implement such features soon.

However its core features are intact, for regular usage e.g chats etc , it is very good to tool to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use WhatsApp business as the second instance of the app

WhatsApp has now officially made it possible to have two WhatsApp accounts without needing any shady third party apps.

WhatsApp has recently come out with an app called [WhatsApp business](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/). It's almost an exact copy of the regular WhatsApp app, and they can both run together on the and phone, without any problems.

There are some minor differences between them, but they are small enough to not get in the way. Main difference would definitely be that when someone good to see more details about you, it will tell them that this is an unverified business account.

Otherwise, it's all the same. You have chats, group chats, statuses, regular and video calling, etc.

It has also some cool features that the regular WhatsApp didn't have. For example: automatic reply, quic reply, and many other.

#### How to set it up:

Download WhatsApp [business from the play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp.w4b), and go through the regular number authentication process. After you're done, you will be able to use both apps on the same phone.

Answer (score -2):

You can use OGwhatsapp to use two numbers on your device. But now a days WhatsApp has started to ban unofficial users of whatsapp so do at your own risk!

[Download OGWhatsapp](http://dw.en.uptodown.com/dl/1422606366/61622a3393d820863d205e8e4e5f10e715097904/ogwhatsapp-2-11-432-multi-android.apk)

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide the download link to WhatsApp+, since it's not available on Play Store though.