# How to use two whatsapp accounts on my rooted Samsung galaxy star pro device

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger

Can I use two whatsapp accounts on same device?
If how
Note: my device is rooted

Comment: WhatsApp now officially lets you do it. More details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/192182/241679) no root needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl) app.
2. Tap WhatsApp icon and you'll be prompted to sign in to the second WhatsApp
3. When it gets to verifying your phone number, use the other number you want to use and select call verification after sms verification fails.
4. Voila, you have one WhatsApp account on your first number and to access the other WhatsApp use the Parallel Space App.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the duel sim galaxy star?

To my knowledge Whatsapp uses a phone number to create an account so if you have duel sim cards it *could* be possible.

For example;- You have your phone with your contacts saved to its local storage and used whatsapp with a first sim's phone number but then swapped it for a second sim with a new number, then opened whatsapp with that phone number the account would be different but obviously all the contacts wouldn't recognise your account as it would be a new one.

So, if you were able to set the default simcard for whatsapp in app settings, in theory, you should be able to have two separate whatsapp accounts on one phone but you would have to verify the number each time you switched account with the code it will want to send to the phone number you want to use at that time.

Do you want to have two official whatsapps installed on one device though? Using them at the same time send/receiving messages to/from both?

Comment: i would comment but i need more rep