# How to run multiple whatsapp accounts?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My Android device is rooted.

I use Parallel Space for running two WhatsApp accounts but Parallel Space gets stuck very frequently.

Please let me know how to run multiple WhatsApp accounts in my Android device in both cases; device is rooted and device is not rooted.

Comment: Maybe using Knox?

Comment: I'm using parallel space on my not rooted Oneplus 3 and it is working just fine. It may be due to you're using the older version of Android or an older device.

Comment: WhatsApp now officially lets you do it. More details [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/192182/241679) no root needed!

Answer (score 1):

There is a custom app based on original whatsapp , named *Whatsapp PLUS* , it allows you to edit complete user interface and as well you can run multiple whatsapp account on a single phone . 
[whatsapp-messenger](/questions/tagged/whatsapp-messenger)

Comment: My advice is, don't use this app. It will lead to getting your account banned by WhatsApp developers.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [GBWhatsapp](http://www.gbmods.co/wp-content/uploads/GBWA3_5.15.html). It runs smoothly here on my 4.2.2. It's arabic website but hope you will find what you need

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps to go run multiple whatsapp accounts:

1. Root your Android device.
2. Make sure that you have WhatsApp app installed on your smartphone.
3. Install [SwitchMe Multiple accounts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme) on your smartphone.
4. Run *SwitchMe Multiple accounts,* it will ask for Superuser request that you need to grant.

Hope It will help you.

Comment: *Simple steps: 1- Root your device.* Almost half of all questions on this website are about how to root or how to save the device after failed root attempt. Too much for calling simple I guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do that without root.

If you have a device with the Google Play Store, go and download Parallel Space app. If you have an arm/arm64 processor, download its extension Parallel Space 64-bit support as well.

After downloading this app, you can run two accounts of not just Whatsapp, but also of Facebook, Messenger, Instagram, Snapchat etc. This will not affect the first app installed in any way. You don't need to do any switching at all. Just add the shortcut of the Parallel app from Parallel Space on your launcher, and it will launch Whatsapp of the second account.

Regards.

Comment: If you actually read the question, you'll notice that the OP has already tried Parallel Space.

Comment: That is the best suggestion I can speak of. Others need device to be rooted

Comment: My device is already rooted. And I am using Parallel Space. I like this app for multiple accounts but unfortunately this app stucks very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

One quite simple way of doing this that often gets overlooked, is adding a new user to the phone if you have android 5 or above, and installing whatsapp on there.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [App Cloner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applisto.appcloner).

From the description:

> Using App Cloner you can create and install multiple copies of your existing apps.

- Note: WhatsApp is available in their premium version. So you can try it on another app and if satisfied - continue to the premium.