# One WhatsApp account, 2 phone numbers

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, roaming

Let's say I have a number in my country and WhatsApp account associated with it. I want to travel far away, where roaming would be ridiculously expensive. Is it possible that I can buy a SIM card local to that country I choose to travel to, and still be able to use my home country's WhatsApp number?

Comment: If you want to use both numbers on the same phone, use the answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/192182/241679) to set that up. Otherwise the answer below is the correct answer, there is no problem using ur old WhatsApp number as long as you don't uninstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to use Whatsapp with another SIM card and your old account, but do not reset or reinstall the app to not provoke number verification.
Source: personal experience; https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/30028016/.