# How to install Amazon FR app alongside Amazon (US)

Tags: applications, installation, localization

This might be as simple as: It cannot be done.

I am an American living in Europe. I have an android phone with multiple accounts (one for each country where I reside).

I would like to be able to install the Amazon FR app alongside the regular Amazon app (US).
Attempting to do give me the following error: duplicate provider authority

Can I get around this?

Update: Each app as well as each URL (amazon.com vs amazon.fr) provides a different set of vendors, items, previous orders, order tracking, invoices, etc.  Both apps are in the Google Play App store and you can search for the Amazon FR app but you can ONLY install it if your logged in account while accessing Google Play is registered in France.

Comment: They are probably sharing the same package name. Is your phone rooted? On rooted devices you can disable and enable any app, not just pre-loaded system ones (some backup utilities such as Titanium Backup refer to this as "freezing/unfreezing"). You could disable the US app and enable the FR one, and vice-verse. It's not the cleanest solution, but it beats uninstalling and re-downloading the two apps each time you want to swap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same app (logged in to different accounts)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27156/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-logged-in-to-differen)

Comment: @geffchang I don't think this is *quite* a duplicate, because he's not just running one app with two accounts, but different regional variants of the app.

Comment: @DanHulme Are there different Amazon apps in the Play Store? What differences do they have? I suppose he can just use the US app, and log-in/log-out to his different accounts. That would still work, and Titanium Backup's Profile feature can help him manage that.

Comment: For a start, it's not clear to me what exact app is the problem. My first thought was that it's the Amazon App Store, but who knows?

Comment: I was assuming Amazon Appstore, which must be side-loaded. Perhaps OP can clarify for us?

Comment: These are indeed 2 different apps. My phone is not rooted but I have been looking for an excuse to do so...
Each app gives you access to a different list of orders and invoices.  Pretty much like logging into amazon.com and amazon.fr in your browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most recent versions of the Amazon app allow for changing countries.

My current version:
6.0.0.100
Build:
6.0.61.71

Comment: Can you include which version of amazon has included this change? So everyone in the future knows which version has added support for this function - thanks in advance! :)