# How to downgrade Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-services

I want to test different versions of Google Play Services and I am wondering if it is possible to downgrade the Google Play Services version of a device?

Comment: What do you mean by "wanting to test different versions of Google Play Services"?Could you be more specific? Cause if you delete updates you will simply revert to the original factory setting/version of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings>apps>all and find Google Play Services. Tap it, then tap 'delete from use' or whatever it is. Then tap on the 'delete updates'
After you've installed your version of the services, remember to tap the button 'Take to use'.

Should work :)

Comment: Settings->Apps->All : Google Play services : Disable

(although I rather like "delete from use" ;) ) You might also want to clear the checkbox on "Show notifications" just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @brit0n Notifications won't show up if the app is disabled.

Comment: I tried it, but whenever I go to the device administrator section to remove "find my device" the settings app stops working. Until I remove "find my device" from administrator section, I can not uninstall updates. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are content to try each version at a separate boot and the above doesn't fulfill you're requirement, you'll have to go the full uninstall and install route.

If you truly want to compare, you'll have some problems getting more than one version present at the same time without source code access. I assume you're already in Developer mode. For more guidance, I suggest you look at others who are trying something similar and the links provided. Here's one example: [How to keep two versions of an app installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19935/how-to-keep-two-versions-of-an-app-installed)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for those unable to fix google play services in android (e.g. China ROMs) ~ due to bootloader problems etc:

1. Reboot your phone to recovery mode using power-volume up
2. Use power button to select factory reset, clear data and cache, confirm.
3. Reboot to factory reset and without cloud restore reinstall google play services (e.g. in Redmi phones install with china ROM google play store)
4. Install all google parts such as normal google PlayStore. Then install apps in google as needed
5. Re backup the phone on cloud and you're set.